I have to show custom validation message on lightning field of lightning record edit form
I have lightning record edit  form with two picklist values.
One is Rating and another is Industry. So when user select Rating as Hot then only i am displaying industry field on Ui. So when user select Rating as Hot and keeps Industry as blank then he should get an validation msg.  if user goes and select another picklist value (Not Hot) , validation message should go away without clicking on next button.
I am using this lwc screen inside flow.
I tried setCustomvalidity(), reportValidity() and SetError() but its not working. Am i doing something wrong??
enter image description here


HTML

<template>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account"  >
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Rating"  onchange={handleChange} class='inputField' required></lightning-input-field>
            <template if:true={showIndustry}>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Industry"  onchange={handleChange} class='myInputField' required></lightning-input-field>
        </template>     
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>


JS
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
export default class LightningRecordEditForm extends LightningElement {

    selectedRating;
    selectedIndustry;
    showIndustry=false;
      handleChange(event) {
        console.log('event detail field Name'+event.target.fieldName);
        let value=event.detail.value;
        if(event.target.fieldName==='Rating'){
            this.selectedRating=value;
            console.log('inside show Field');
            if(this.selectedRating==='Hot'){
                console.log('inside true');
                this.showIndustry=true;
            }else{
                console.log('inside false');
                this.showIndustry=false;
            }
        }
        if(event.detail.field==='Industry'){
            this.selectedIndustry=value;
        }

        var f = this.template.querySelector('.myInputField');
        if(this.selectedRating==='Hot' &&  ( this.selectedIndustry===undefined ||  this.selectedIndustry===null) ){
            console.log('inside error');
            
                f.setCustomValidity('Please select Industry as you selected rating as Hot');
        }else{
            console.log('inside else');
            f.setCustomValidity('');
        }


    }
    
}



Does this answer your question? LWC setCustomValidity on lightning-input-field

I have next screen in my case... validation rule will fire only when we try to create or update a case. But in our case we are going to next screen on clicking of next botton..not creating or updating any record.
